# Laravel Eloquent way to do AND operation on mysql table

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I am a novice in Laravel. 
I have a table audience_tags like this:

```
tag  | audience
Tall | Anurag
Nice | Anurag
Tall | Kapil
Nice | Simon
```

So,

```
If I query for ['Tall'] it should return Anurag, Kapil
If I query for ['Nice'] it should return Anurag, Simon
If I query for ['Tall', 'Nice'] it should only return Anurag
```

Currently, I am doing like this:

```
$audienceIds = DB::table("audience_tags")->whereIn("tag", $request->tagIds)->pluck("audience");
```

But it return Anurag, Kapil and Simon for ['Tall', 'Nice']

Comment: `If I query for ['Tall', 'Nice'] it should only return Anurag`. Why? It normally returns rows whose `tag` is either `Tall` or `Nice`

Comment: I know. But i need to do AND operation among the tags and audiences.

Comment: You want to perform separate rows as one row. But that's not how `mysql` works. Maybe you should preprocess the table to convert it like `(distinct) audience | tag[]` and then make your query as `where tag[] is subarray of request->tagIds`.

Comment: It stretches credulity that you spelt your own name wrong :-(

Answer (score 1):

You will not be able to escape a `group by` with that structure

```
$audiences = \DB::table("audience_tags")
    ->whereIn("tag", $request->tagIds)
    ->groupBy('audience')
    ->havingRaw('count(tag) = ?', count($request->tagIds))
    ->pluck('audience');
```

With the tables `audiences` and `tags` declared, you can make use of the relation `belongToMany` between `Audience` and `Tag` models (assuming `tag_id` is the primary key in table `Tags`)

```
$tagIds = $request->tagIds;
$audiences = Audience::whereHas('tags', function($tag) use ($tagIds) {
    $tag->whereIn('tag_id', $tagIds);
})->get(); //or pluck whatever attribute
```

Comment: Well, I'm sure you could avoid a GROUP BY (`SELECT x.name FROM my_table x JOIN my_table y ON y.name = x.name AND y.tag = 'tall' WHERE x.tag = 'nice';`, but why would you?

Comment: in a better structure, you would have a `tags` table with real unique ids, and another `audiences` table with all the possible audience and have a pivot table between them. The query would have been faster and not requiring a `group by` on a non string field

Comment: In real there is a table for tags, a table for audiences and a pivot table. I just gave an example here for the ease of understanding the real problem.

Comment: @Anurag then you should do a query on the `audience` table with a `whereHas`. that would be faster and simpler

Answer (score 0):

A raw query:

```
SELECT name 
  FROM my_table 
 WHERE tag IN('tall','nice') 
 GROUP 
    BY name 
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2;
```

Comment: I have tried this one but it won’t work for dynamic set of tags.

Comment: Yes it will. You just replace '2' with a count of the number of arguments in IN().